# error in cuda shared memory static allocation

Tags: c, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I wrote a CUDA code using shared memory like this:

```
__global__ void matrix_mul_shared(float *ad,float *bd,float *cd,int N)
{
    float pvalue=0;
    int TILE=blockDim.x;
    int ty=threadIdx.y;
    int tx=threadIdx.x;

    //allocate shared memory per block
    __shared__ float ads[1][1];
    __shared__ float bds[1][1];

 .
```

.
.
}

This code works , but the following code fails;

```
__global__ void matrix_mul_shared(float *ad,float *bd,float *cd,int N)
{
    float pvalue=0;
    int TILE=blockDim.x;
    int ty=threadIdx.y;
    int tx=threadIdx.x;

    //allocate shared memory per block
    __shared__ float ads[TILE][TILE];
    __shared__ float bds[TILE][TILE];

 .
. 
.
}
```

The compiler is expecting something constant at the lines where I am allocating shared memory. It says(I forgot the exact error  but it is something like this):

> The parameters should be a constant

I was able to use printf and print the value of TILE, and it is coming out 1. so why this error?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error you are receiving is

```
error: expression must have a constant value
```

The variable `TILE` is not a constant in the sense meant by the compiler. The compiler is asking something known at compile time as dimension of your shared memory array.

A possible solution:

```
#define TILE 16

__global__ void matrix_mul_shared(float *ad,float *bd,float *cd,int N)
{
    ...

    __shared__ float ads[TILE][TILE];

    ...
}
```

Comment: so you mean at the compile time TILE is not a constant but still blockDimx.x, which is not yet evaluated to 1?

Comment: @user25108 Yes, the problem here is that the value of `TILE` is unknown at compile time.